# Executing YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent() from google youtube api in a separate class from MainActivity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-youtube-api

I am passing in the MainActivity object to the constructor of a class Alarm. Class Alarm is instantiated in class MainActivity with a constructor that takes the MainActivity object (denoted like
new Alarm(this)). In the Alarm class I have YoutubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(mainActivityObject, ...), but I get a null pointer exception when I have made sure that my mainActivityObject variable contains the MainActivity object.

```
public class MainActivity {
    ...
    Alarm a = new Alarm(this);
    ...
}

public class Alarm extends BroadcastReciever {
    Activity mainActivityObject;
    public Alarm(Activity main) {
        mainActivityObject = main;
    }
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) { // when onReceive is executed, I get a java.lang.NullPointerException
       Intent i = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent((Activity) mainActivityObject, "apikey", "youtubevideoid", 0, true, true);
       mainActivityObject.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Intent playVideo = YouTubeIntents.createPlayVideoIntentWithOptions(arg0, "apikey", true, true); instead.